# Creating two seperate validation messages for the same attribute

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I'm trying to create two separate validation messages for the same validation attribute.
There are two rules that use "**before_or_equal**" - the `end_time` has to be "**before_or_equal**" start_time and also the `end_time` has to be after **5:00 (time)**. The validation works, but I can't seem to find a way to create a working custom message for the latter.

I tried to specify the rule by including it literally with the value, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is what the custom request validation looks like for the `end_time` at the moment.

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'end_time' => ['after_or_equal:start_time', 'after_or_equal:5:00'],
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'end_time.after_or_equal'     => 'Message 1',
            'end_time.after_or_equal:5:00'    => 'Message 2',
        ];
    }
```

Comment: I edited the code because of the mistake of copying wrong pieces of code (they were not for the corresponding attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:date` for your custom error messages.

Example:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'end_time' => ['after_or_equal:start_time', 'after_or_equal:5:00'],
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'end_time.after_or_equal' => 'the :attribute time must be after :date',
        ];
    }
```

The replaced value is actual value of first input of the validator

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if i understand your question correctly, but are you looking for something like this ?

```
public function rules()
{
    return $this->messages("end_time", [
        "after_or_equal",
        "after_or_equal:5:00",
    ]);
}

public function messages(string $Key, array $CustomAttributes)
{
    $Exceptions = [
        "end_time" => [
            "after_or_equal" => "Message 1",
            "after_or_equal:5:00" => "Message 2"
        ]
    ];
    $Exception = [
        $Key => []
    ];
    foreach ($CustomAttributes as $Attribute) {
        array_push($Exception[$Key], $Exceptions[$Key][$Attribute]);
    }
    return $Exception;
}
```